# Getting full field type of ICompilationUnit

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to get type of fields declared in java file (`ICompilationUnit`).

```
for (IType type : compilationUnit.getTypes()) {
  for (IField iField : type.getFields()) { 
     typesig = iField.getTypeSignature()
  }
}
```

`getTypeSignature()` - returns type name, but without the package name.

It's possible to obtain package name using:
`IType.resolveType(String typeName)`
But this method is heavy and takes some time to complete.

Is there another way to get the full type name (with package)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using JDT's Java model, the approach in the question (using IType.resolveType()) is the correct one.

If you need resolved types of many elements consider using an AST with resolved bindings. That way you pay the price for resolving only once.

Answer (score 0):

To use type signature, use this code:

```
Signature.getSignatureSimpleName(iField.getTypeSignature())
```